# Подскажите пожалуйста паттерн для скайп логина

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Вот например для числового значения типа номера карты я использую:

```
/[^0-9]/
```

Он удаляет из принимаемой строки все символы кроме цифр.\

Подскажите пожалуйста паттерн для логина скайп, честно говоря не знаю какие символы там разрешены, может дефисы подчеркивания, может точки, а может нет.

Comment: @ReinRaus, а в скайпе ж можно и микрософтовскую учетку использовать - это тоже учитывать?

Comment: @Grundy Вы имеете ввиду как можно авторизоваться в системе? Там еще номер телефона, и фейсбуком можно зайти, но думаю, что чтобы позвонить кому-нибудь достаточно знать его логин.

Comment: @ReinRaus, а там разве при авторизации логин не будет такой же как в facebook или через что вошли?

Comment: На текущий момент в вопросе полностью корректный логин скайпа. Я ошибся

Comment: @Grundy как я понял при авторизации через фейсбук отсутствует логин скайп как таковой. Сейчас попробую посмотреть для майкрософт

Answer (score 0):

Вот так вот вроде:

```
/[^a-z0-9\._\-]/
```

Удаляет всё кроме точек, подчеркиваний, дефисов, латиницы, цифр.

Comment: запятые еще можно и длина 6-32

Comment: зачем мне длина? совсем не обязательный атребут

Comment: да и в preg_replace(); если длину устанавливаешь, то не работает функция